# How does triangle inequality imply this?

Tags: inequality

I am banging my head against the wall over this easy equation, but I can't see it right now.

> [image]

How the triangle inequality imply $|x_0 + y_0| = |x_0| + |y_0|$?

**EDIT**: I got it, Basically $2|y_0| = |2y_0|$.

**EDIT2**: never mind, I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

**If you would have been posted the whole Lemma 3.0.1** from Lauritzen, [Lectures on Convex Sets](http://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/~lavric/lauritzen.pdf), then would have noticed (not only you, but also others) that $x_0\in F$ (where $F$ is a convex set) is such that $$|x_0|=\inf\{|x|:x\in F\}.$$ Moreover, $y_0\in F$ is another point with $|y_0|=\inf\{|x|:x\in F\}$, so $|y_0|=|x_0|$.
Now $z=\frac 12(x_0+y_0)$ has the obvious properties: $z\in F$ and $|z|\leq|x_0|$ (from the triangle inequality).
Since $|x_0|=\inf\{|x|:x\in F\}$ and $z\in F$ we get $|x_0|\le |z|$. Then $|z|=|x_0|$ and from here $$|x_0+y_0|=2|x_0|=|x_0|+|y_0|.$$